# How to add A record in bind9

Tags: linux, bind

I have CentOS server on which I configured bind9. Everything works fine. But I can't add an A record for client (other CentOS server with apache on it).It's hostname is **apache.local** with IP **192.168.0.106**. My question is how exactly I add it as an A record in the zones so the dns resolves it?

Comment: Is it a local DNS server you are trying to make, to resolve hostnames to local ip adresses such as 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x, 192.168.x.x?

Comment: Yes, it is a local DNS with IP 192.168.0.107

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to twig this for centOS but something along the lines of

**cat /etc/hostname**

```
dns-office
```

**cat /etc/hosts**

```
yourIP dns-office.local
```

**cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "zone1" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.zone1";
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
};

dnssec-enable no;

allow-recursion { any; };
allow-query { any; };
allow-query-cache { any; };

listen-on { 127.0.0.1; yourIP; };
```

**/etc/bind/db.zone1**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dns-office.local. root.dns-office.local. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      dns-office.local.
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1

;your sites
computer1.local IN A 192.168.x.x;
computer2.local IN A 192.168.x.x;
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
search local
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

ping computer1.local and get a reply.
Their are alot of material out their on how to accomplish this from Ubuntu, digitalocean with more. Search for example "configure ubuntu local dns" on Google.